# Completeness of Poincare disc

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

It is known that the Poincare disc $\mathbb D=\{z:|z|<1\}$ with with the usual Riemannian metric $\frac{\mathrm dz^2}{(1-|z|^2)^2}$ is geodesically complete. Also for any $0\neq x\in\mathbb D\cap\mathbb R$ $\gamma_0(t)=tx$ is a geodesic joining $0$ and $x$. Can any one show explicitly how the corresponding maximal geodesic extends to $\mathbb R$?

It seems that from the above discussion that $\gamma_0(t)=t$ is a geodesic which reaches the boundary in finite time! What is going wrong here?

Comment: It is not true that $\gamma (t)=t$ is a geodesic.....

Comment: @Arctic. $\gamma_0(t)=tx$ is a geodesic. After reparametrization $\gamma(t)=t$ becomes a geodesic.

Comment: a geodesic should have constant speed 1, right? $\gamma(t) = t$ would have speed $\frac{1}{1-|t|^2}$ at $\gamma(t) = t$.